# Comparing 2 HashSets for common object

Tags: java, list, set

I have one question, I have two HashSets,

```
Set<String> list1 = new HashSet<String>(oldList1);
Set<String> list2 = new HashSet<String>(oldList2);
```

And I would like to check if a "String" in `list1` is present in `list2`. What would be the fastest way to go trough this? Keeping in mind that both sets have over 10k Strings, so something relatively fast would be nice.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't call a `Set` `list` - is confusing.

Comment: `list2.retainAll(list1)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether there is *any* string in `list1` that is also in `list2`, you can just write

```
!Collections.disjoint(list1, list2)
```

which is true if they have any elements in common.  If you want to find the answer, just do the straightforward loop:

```
for (String str : list1) {
  if (list2.contains(str)) {
    return str;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks! but I would also like to what that String is

Comment: Then just do a loop: `for (String str : list1) { if (list2.contains(str)) { return str; }}` ...which does the same thing anyway, and you're not going to get more efficient than that.  (Though frankly 10k elements isn't big enough to worry about.)

Comment: @BoristheSpider it doesn't seem worth it to mutate the data structure if it's not actually necessary?  The simple loop does the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Set restriction to add duplicate. Method `add()` will help you find all identical strings.

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present
>   (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to
>   this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ?
>   e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element,
>   the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination
>   with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never
>   contain duplicate elements.

```
    Set<String> list1 = new HashSet<String>();
    list1.add("a");
    list1.add("b");
    list1.add("c");
    Set<String> list2 = new HashSet<String>();
    list2.add("b");
    list2.add("c");
    list2.add("d");
    Set<String> listCommon = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String element : list2) {
        if (!list1.add(element)) {
            listCommon.add(element);
        }
    }
    // all collected duplicates
    for (String element : listCommon) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```